# Not able to understand the Javascript output

Tags: javascript

The below code is printing "helloundefined", but I expected it to print "Hello there".

```
var proto = {
    age: function(a)    {
        console.log(a+this.val)
    }
};
;
var a = { val: "there" };
a = Object.create(proto);

a.age("hello");
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code and watch what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var a = { val: "there" };
> ```

You have assigned an object to `a`

> ```
> a = Object.create(proto);
> ```

… which you *immediately* overwrite with a new object that has no connection to the object you created on the previous line at all.

Said previous object has no references pointing to it left and gets garbage collected.

You seem to be looking for [`Object.setPrototypeOf(a, proto);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) (warning: ES6).

```js
var proto = {
    age: function(a)    {
        console.log(a+this.val)
    }
};
;
var a = { val: "there" };
Object.setPrototypeOf(a, proto); 
a.age("hello");
```

Comment: ok...understood so the correct way to add the property 'val'   will be to write a.val="there" below object.create..

Comment: @MukulChakravarty: Yes, exactly, that's how you should do it. `Object.setPrototypeOf` is a bit despised